Unexpected Error Diagnostics for erb files
My current neovim (lazyvim) show weird errors for my .erb files.
How can I find out which linter is showing them to me in order to configure it correctly?
My linter for ruby are

erb-lint for erb
rubocop

My installed lsp

ruby-lsp

This error was not shown before. Only after an update I see the errors.


Guessing: rubocop tends not to be able to cope with erb and gives this kind of error when I run it on erb files.
Note: I haven't used erb-lint before, so maybe that will change the behaviour of rubocop.

Those errors are coming from Prism, which is the primary dependency of ruby-lsp.  ruby-lsp does not handle .erb files well.  Shopify states that they do handle erb in their vscode extension, but for other editors some custom code is needed.  I've tested it extensively in both nvim and vscode - it always lights up my erbs like a christmas tree and doesn't understand any of the tags.
In VSCode, I uncheck the ruby-lsp: ERB Support config option, and I choose erb-formatter as my default auto-format option.
In Nvim, you can configure the nvim-lspconfig to use a different formatter for erb or eruby files.
